# android studio project with fire base error

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Android application where I initially populated a RecyclerView with dummy data in the MainActivity. Later, I integrated Firebase Database to fetch real-time data for populating the RecyclerView. Below is the code snippet before and after the Firebase integration:

```
// Previous version of MainActivity without Firebase integration
package com.example.quizonline

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.quizonline.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    // Variable declarations
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    lateinit var quizModelList : MutableList<QuizModel>
    lateinit var adapter : QuizListAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Initialization and population of quizModelList with dummy data
        quizModelList = mutableListOf()
        getDataFromFirebase()
    }

    // Function to setup RecyclerView
    private fun setupRecyclerView(){
        adapter = QuizListAdapter(quizModelList)
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    // Function to add dummy data to quizModelList (before Firebase)
    private fun getDataFromFirebase(){
        // Dummy data creation
        val listQuestionModel = mutableListOf<QuestionModel>()
        listQuestionModel.add(QuestionModel("What is android?", mutableListOf("Language","OS","Product","None"),"OS"))
        listQuestionModel.add(QuestionModel("Who owns android?", mutableListOf("Apple","Google","Samsung","Microsoft"),"Google"))
        listQuestionModel.add(QuestionModel("Which assistant android uses?", mutableListOf("Siri","Cortana","Google Assistant","Alexa"),"Google Assistant"))

        // Adding dummy quizModel to quizModelList
        quizModelList.add(QuizModel("1", "Programming", "All the basic programming", "10",listQuestionModel))

        // Setting up RecyclerView
        setupRecyclerView()
    }
}
```

After Firebase Integration:

```
// MainActivity with Firebase integration
package com.example.quizonline

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.quizonline.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    // Variable declarations
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    lateinit var quizModelList : MutableList<QuizModel>
    lateinit var adapter : QuizListAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Initialization of quizModelList and fetching data from Firebase
        quizModelList = mutableListOf()
        getDataFromFirebase()
    }

    // Function to setup RecyclerView
    private fun setupRecyclerView(){
        adapter = QuizListAdapter(quizModelList)
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }

    // Function to fetch data from Firebase
    private fun getDataFromFirebase(){
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { dataSnapshot->
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children){
                        val quizModel = snapshot.getValue(QuizModel::class.java)
                        if (quizModel != null) {
                            quizModelList.add(quizModel)
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Setting up RecyclerView after fetching data
                setupRecyclerView()
            }
    }
}
```

In the updated version, Firebase Database is integrated to dynamically fetch data for populating the RecyclerView. However, after this integration, the data is not displayed correctly. Can someone help me identify the issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Firebase APIs are asynchronous and return immedately before the query completes.  The listener you provide will be invoked some time later.  Your code is assuming that all of the data in `quizModelList` is ready immediately as soon as `getDataFromFirebase` returns, but it is not.  Add some logging statements to better understand the order in which your code executes.  You will have to apply some form of asynchronous programming to delay rendering your recyclerview until the data becomes available.

Comment: @Doug: `setupRecyclerView` (which creates an adapter and attaches it to the view) is being called from within the `addOnSuccessListener` callback, so after the data has loaded. 

Comment: Well i'd suggest you log the data from firebase and compare its structure to the data in the dummy list

Comment: Did you try to add a Failure listener to see if something goes wrong?